# SwiftyJSON not working with socket.io

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift2, swifty-json

I've been cracking my head for a few days and still can't get it working so I've decided to ask for help.

[image]

From the photo attached, you can see that I have stringify the data(I believe the data received is an array) and it has 3 subscripts.

And I have included SwiftyJSON, and created a constant json, the rest of the code are self explanatory.

Why am I getting nil?

Comment: what is the type of variable `data`?

Comment: @Ismail I believe it is an array but I'm not very certain, according to the docs from socket.io http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/

Comment: would you print the type of it and tell me?

Comment: just `print(data.dynamicType, data)` and tell me what is the output.

Comment: @Ismail it is an array

Comment: Array<AnyObject> [(
        {
        ID = 1;
        Mileage = "27.08";
        Name = "John Doe";
    },
        {
        ID = 2;
        Mileage = "2084.42";
        Name = "Alex Booker";
    },
        {
        ID = 4;
        Mileage = "0.23";
        Name = hung;
    }
)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what is the problem.
If you get output out of `print(json)` you should call the like:

```
let name = json[0][0]["Name"].stringValue
```

Comment: Oh thanks!!! I'm relieved now! but I get Optional("John Doe") though, how can I get rid of that optional?

Comment: @Ismail SO doesn't allows me to upvote, says reputation below than 15